# Using Index position for next or prev songs in MediaPlayer Class

Tags: java, android-studio, arraylist, audio-player, android-music-player

- Hi I have been feeling very overwhelmed and discouraged I am stuck. I
  want to have more than one song in my music player and add next and
  prev  buttons. Can it be done with using an ArrayList of songs and
  then using the index position? Can someone write a small code snippet
  to modify my code below and tell me how to add prev and next button.
  I was hoping if everytime next is clicked index position is
  incremented thus causing the next element of arraylist to start.

  My XML CODE :

  ```
  <Button
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
      android:id="@+id/play"
      android:text="Play" />


  <Button
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
      android:id="@+id/pause"
      android:text="Pause" />


  <Button
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
      android:id="@+id/next"
      android:text="NEXT" />


  <Button
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
      android:id="@+id/prev"
      android:text="PREV" />
  ```

  AND MY JAVA CODE:

  package com.example.next;

  import android.media.MediaPlayer;
  import android.provider.MediaStore;
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.Button;

  import java.time.chrono.MinguoChronology;
  import java.util.ArrayList;

  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  ```
  private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


      Button play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
      Button pause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause);
      Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
      Button prev = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prev);

      final ArrayList<SONG> songs = new ArrayList<>();
      songs.add(new SONG (R.raw.goblinost));
      songs.add(new SONG ( R.raw.khabboon));
      songs.add(new SONG (R.raw.startover));
      songs.add(new SONG (R.raw.tujhekitna));

      SONG song = songs.get(position); // (I CANT GET THE POSITION ITS IN RED IN MY CODE) 

      mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, song.getSong());

      play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              mMediaPlayer.start();
          }
      });

      pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              mMediaPlayer.pause();
          }
      });


  }
  ```

  }
  [you can see the error][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrE8o.png

  My custom class:

  package com.example.next;

  public class SONG {

  ```
  private int mSong;

  public SONG (int song) {
      mSong = song;
  }

  public int getSong () {
      return mSong;
  }
  ```

  }

WHAT SHOULD I do so my next and pause button increment or decrement the index positions and play songs